# How to use external jar containing entity class, repository interface and service class into a spring boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa, jar

Problem: How to use external jar containing entity class, repository interface and service class into a spring boot project.

Steps done:
1- Created a maven project with
a- entity class and marked those with @entity @table @data annotation
b- repository interface with jpa repository and @repository annotation
c- service class containing some logic on how to get data from db and do some processing over it. Tried @autowired and @requiredargcontructor for repository interface
d- ran mvn clean install package command and jar is created in target folder and used that jar in step #2

2- created a normal spring boot project with web dependency.
a- controller class
b- service class calling service class methods of external jar project #1

Error: while calling the service class methods from jar it throws error , this.userrepository is null

Can someone please tell me
1- am i defining right annotation in external jar service class ?
2- how to export proper jar of that project
3- how to use that in spring boot project, tried @entityscan, @componentscan, @enablejparepositories method too

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in your spring boot project a @Configuration with the @ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.library.package")

With the @ComponentScan, the context scans the library for services and the other beans.

Example

```html
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.library.package")
public class YourLibraryConfig {
}
```